# How do I re-conciliate using a "Windows sub-process" and running a "console-less" python program

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

My program displays my ping on a canvas drawn in tkinter. The program finds my ping using a thread to loop through a Windows sub-process so the main thread isn't interrupted (I still need the main thread running so the program can detect mouse movement so the user can drag the window). The thread finds ping by pinging an IP address and storing the result as a string, and then manipulating the string. For example, I can `ping google.com` and the result `... Average = 234ms` becomes `234ms.`

I used PyInstaller to compile this program as a stand alone exe. I used the `--noconsole` option to get rid of the console window and as expected, the console windows no longer appears. The problem now is the thread pauses at the sub-process. The `--noconsole` option is somehow preventing the execution of the sub process.

The result is the thread stops progressing, even if the main program is still running.

Here I start the thread

```
t = threading.Thread(target=get_ping)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```

And here is the threaded function that finds the ping

```
def get_ping():
    global latency
    global IP

    while 1==1:
        #Launches 'command' windowless and waits until finished; finds ping
        suinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
        suinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
        #thread pauses here
        x = subprocess.Popen \
        (["ping.exe", IP], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=suinfo)
        latency = "red"

        #Extracts ping from string e.g. "...Averge = 231ms" --> "231ms" 
        x = str(x.communicate()[0])
        x = list(x[-10:])
        i = 7 
        char_list = []
        while i > 0:
            char_list = char_list + [x[i]]
            if x[i] == " ":
                break
            i-=1
        x = "".join(char_list)
        x = x[::-1]
        latency = x
```

And as one can see, the thread pauses here

```
        #thread pauses here
        x = subprocess.Popen \
        (["ping.exe", IP], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=suinfo)
```

My question is pretty general. I would be more specific if I could. **How do I re-conciliate using a Window's sub-process and running a console-less python program?**

Comment: When I run the program as a script, there is no console. The console only appears when I run PyInstaller. Then when I add the option --noconsole the console disappears but the program freezes.

Comment: I take that back. The console appears when I run the script. I'm trying to fix that. That way I won't need to use the option --noconosle (hopefully).

Comment: There is no way to log any exception. The program just stops running at that line. I can't do this in line A `x = subprocess.Popen(["ping.exe", IP], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=suinfo, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` and then this in line B `output = x.stdout.readlines()`

Comment: It's working! But why!? I did `try: subprocess.Popen(...)` and `except Exception as e: logfile.write(str(e))` and I did `import io` and i created a file `logfile.txt` ... I thought you just meant to log the error in a file with the I/O module.

Comment: No, there is no exception. What I meant to say is that the program is working now. As soon as I added `try` and `except` the program started working, and the thread was able to loop. Is this what you expected?

Comment: I'm trying, but now I get this error despite doing everything exactly the same `except exception as e:` and `NameError: name 'exception' is not defined`

Comment: That's really odd because the capital `E` didn't matter before, and I copied and pasted the exact same code into the reduced version of my program which runs without the error. Now I have a new error: `logfile.write(stre(e))`, `TypeError: must be unicode, not str`

Comment: I wrote `import codecs` and `logfile.write(e.decode('utf-8'))` but I get `AttributeError: 'exceptions.NameError' object has not attribute 'decode'`

Comment: I changed `logfile.write(str(e))` to `logfile.write(unicode(e))` but I get the error `logfile.write(unicode(e)) IOError: not writable`